# Does Win32 provide a GetDateTimeFormat to obtain a unified date-time string, in analogy to GetDateFormat and GetTimeFormat?

Tags: datetime, winapi, localization, internationalization

I know Win32 has the NLS function [GetDateFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318086(VS.85).aspx), e.g.:

```
GetDateFormat(…, …, …, "dddd','MM','y", …, …);
```

and it also has the function [GetTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318130(VS.85).aspx), e.g.:

```
GetTimeFormat(…, …, …, "tt ss':'hh':'mm", …, …);
```

But is there a way to format both the date and time at once, like a hypothetical GetDateTimeFormat function?

```
GetDateTimeFormat(…, …, …, "tt dddd' - 'ss':'y';'hh':'mm MM", …, …);
```

**Note:** The format string is intentionally constructed to demonstrate that not all format strings are linearly separable. Thus, this is not the trivial problem that it appears to simply concatenate the results of GetDateFormat and GetTimeFormat.

Comment: Must be that island they discovered under the letter A of "Atlantic".  They'll be in for a rude shock when they get electricity :)

Comment: i'm all for making fun of people who have language and customs different from mine. But even though my software will never be used by anyone besides those in the eastern timezone of North America, i'd still like to be able to support such things.

Comment: If you don't mind including <atltime.h> the CTime class has a Format member that takes a strftime style string.

Comment: I wish you wouldn't have accepted an answer here. The accepted answer doesn't answer the question, and it doesn't really even provide enough details to approach a solution.

Comment: @CodyGray Sometimes the answer is, *"No, that cannot be done."*  There's no shame in an answer like that - if it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember having the same problem sometime ago. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to format a string with mixed date and time fields. Trying to do it in two steps is error prone, since the first substitution might generate words whose letters are mistaken for format codes.

My solution at the time was to scan the format string manually and generate the output by calling `GetDateFormat()` and `GetTimeFormat()` for each code. This can be optimized by grouping consecutive time or date codes if needed.